# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' android error

Tags: java, android, gradle

I know this question has been asked previously but still I am not getting the answer for it. The code was working properly but when I tried to integrate it with firebase I started getting this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have tried building cleaning project but none of them are working. This is my gradle file

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.protechlabz.www.sns"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Shut down Android Studio, and reboot your computer. Then start AS again

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have got around this problem my removing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

from the dependencies and then adding the following lines

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

It removed the error. So thanks for your support